# Cross-Object Apex Update

Tags: apex, trigger

Trying to update a Lookup ID of an object related to Opportunity. New to Apex and I'm missing something pretty fundamental I believe.

```
trigger UpdateABC on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
  for(Opportunity editedOpportunity : trigger.new) 

 if(OppTriggerField != null) {
    editedOpportunity.OppTriggerField__r.Opportunity__r.Id = editedOpportunity.OppTriggerField;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Id` is not a writeable field. You should instead assign to the relationship itself.

`editedOpportunity.OppTriggerField__r.Opportunity__c = <some id>;`

Comment: I get this error when I try that: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.UpdateLinvioPmt: line 5, column 1

Comment: Then you have a null somewhere in that relationship chain. This won't work if, for example, your `OppTriggerField__r` relationship is null.

Comment: But it's not null. I do not know how to troubleshoot. Thanks for your help, but I am a novice and am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the relationship. When the Opp is updated, I'm not updating the Opportunity. I'm updating a related Object with the ID of the Opportunity

Comment: Again, you have a null value somewhere in your object graph. You are assigning a value 'X' to the field C in the relationship A -> B -> C, where A is an object and B/C are lookup fields, which requires non-null values for every object in that chain. You can fix this by checking for null values before you do this assignment.

Comment: There are literally two objects at play here. Opp and Custom Object. I am grabbing the Opportunity ID and passing it to a field on the Custom Object. I have no idea which field could be null.

Comment: There are 3 objects at play here: Oppty and 2 lookup fields. I think also you've pasted only a partial example, as `OppTriggerField` in your code above does not match any field or variable.